# Album art now showing on media app in Automotive OS

Tags: android-automotive

I am using UAMP on automotive OS but album art is not displayed correctly.
This issue on the github explains about the bitmaps using too much memory and using ContentProviders and local URIs. (https://github.com/android/uamp/issues/235)

Did anyone implement this already or has some samples on how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved by the UAMP team: https://github.com/android/uamp/pull/427